# what's the complete rules about a staitc data member of enclosing class used in a member definition of nested class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A{
  struct B{
      void func(){
          auto d = a;
      }
  };
  static int a;
};
int main(){
}
```

Consider the above code,several rules are performed,Firstly,**unqualified-lookup**
[[basic.lookup.unqual#8.3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#8.3)

> For the members of a class X, a name used in a member function body, in a default argument, in a noexcept-specifier, in the brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member, or in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of X, following the member's declarator-id32, shall be declared in one of the following ways
>
> > if X is a nested class of class Y, shall be a member of Y, or shall be a member of a base class of Y (this lookup applies in turn to Y's enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class)

So,after `a` undergo unqualified-lookup rules, the declaration was found in enclosing class A.However,I also find a rule in [[class.mfct.non-static#3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct.non-static#3),It says:

> Similarly during name lookup, when an unqualified-id used in the definition of a member function for class X resolves to a static member, an enumerator or a nested type of class X or of a base class of X, the unqualified-id is transformed into a qualified-id in which the nested-name-specifier names the class of the member function. These transformations do not apply in the template definition context.

Does the second rule require `a` be transformed to `B::a`,if it is,it would be ill-formed,because in class `B`,there is no declaration about `a`.so how to understand the second rule?

Comment: The second rule doesn't apply here. `a` is not a static member, an enumerator or a nested type of class `B` or of a base class of `B`.

Comment: @cigien @user7860670 you mean that here `a` does not need to be transformed,because `a` is not a static member of `B` that is the class of member `func` where `a` is used.So the second rule does not apply,only unqualifed-lookup applies?

Comment: @cigien and Is there anything other rules apply on `a`,such let `a` transformed to `A::a` in my question?

Comment: That's a tough question. Are you asking if there's *any* rule in the standard that conflicts? No idea. But the first rule alone resolves the lookup for `a`, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @cigien okay,however,unqualified-lookup can find these names even if `a` is a static member of `B` or of a base class of `B`,why the second rule need to list specially,I don't understand the purpose of the second rule,could you interpret that.

Comment: I think it's needed for cases like `struct B{ void func(){ auto d = a; } struct A { static int a; }; };` where the first rule doesn't resolve it.

Comment: @cigien if the first rule does not lookup a name for `a` in your example,the second rule aslo wouldn't apply,it means the second rule occur after the first rule succeed find the name.So think the example doest not interpret that. Attach a compiled result: https://godbolt.org/z/RfgDBj

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean (I'm not even sure my example is correct). Why don't you post a separate question explaining what you would like an explanation for?

Comment: @cigien a good idea,I will prepare to do this